# How to use if inside an if in C#

Tags: c#, if-statement

I know it's a dummy question but my brain stopped on this problem. I have an if statement like this :

```
if(entity.Price != 100000
&& entity.Area != 2000
&& entity.Number != 55)

{
//make the code work
}
```

What I want to add in this statement is this:

```
if(entity.Type == 3)
{
 if(entity.Fraction <= 0.3)
 {
 //Make the exactly same code work
 }
}
else
{
  //Make the same code work again.
}
```

How can I combine these 3 ifs together? Thanks.

Comment: Just add more `&&`s?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following updated question, here is another try ...

```
if ((entity.Price != 100000 && entity.Area != 2000 && entity.Number != 55)
 || (entity.Type != 3 || entity.Fraction <= 0.3))
{
  // Do stuff
}
```

Of course if you break those three statements out in to separate Boolean values that are appraised first then it is more readable.

Answer (score 4):

Just string them all together with AND conditions:

```
if(entity.Price != 100000
   && entity.Area != 2000
   && entity.Number != 55
   && entity.Type == 3
   && entity.Fraction <= 0.3)
{
    //make the code work
}
```

Comment: Hmm I understood he wanted or-clause?

Comment: @Esko Where do you get that from? **Edit** Ah, yes, I see it now ^^ Well spotted! **Edit 2**: After the latest edit by OP I'm lost again o_O

Comment: I didn't.  It wasn't exactly clear, but I took the 3 if statements he mentioned to be (1) the first three, (2) the first one in the second statement, and (3) the second one in the second statement.

Comment: I updated the question. Thanks.

Comment: @ManfredRadlwimmer from way he wrote "want the same code to execute", thought me ment either of the conditions to be true. I might be wrong.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you want this:

```
if(entity.Price != 100000 && entity.Area != 2000 && entity.Number != 55 && entity.Type == 3 && entity.Fraction <= 0.3)     
{
   //Make the exactly same code work
}
```

Comment: I updated the question. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I think there is no need for such confusions since you are familiar with `&&` you can combine the remaining conditions also with the above using an `&&`. I have another suggestion that is please check for null before accessing values from `entity`

```
if(entity!=null && entity.Price != 100000
            && entity.Area != 2000
            && entity.Number != 55
            && entity.Type == 3
            && entity.Fraction <= 0.3)
{
    // process true statements
}
```

Comment: I updated the question. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

if(entity.Type == 3 &&entity.Fraction <= 0.3 )
{     }